# All buttons firing at the same time when clicking

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to create a favorite-button for every video thumbnail that is generated by `"id"`, but every time I click one of the buttons all of them fire at the same time so instead of getting the correct value of the video-id I get only the first id from the list of videos.

In conclusion the button kind of works but does not get the correct values.

I've tried a few things but sadly they did not work, the output being the same or resulted in an error.

1. I generated different ids and names for my buttons hoping that they will not fire at the same time.
2. I moved the buttons outside the generated thumbnail code and applied a static value to see if I would get the correct id.

video.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var video_id    = $("input[name='video_id']").val();
    var vwidth      = 854;
    var vheight     = 520;
    var playerc     = $("#player-container");
    var width       = playerc.width();
    var height      = Math.round(width / (vwidth / vheight));
    });

$("button[id='favorite']").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: base_url + '/ajax.php?s=video_favorite',
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {video_id: video_id},
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.status == '1') {
                    $("button[id='favorite']").html(response.count);
                    $("button[id='favorite']").prop('disabled', true);
                } else {
                    $("#response-container").html(close + response.msg);
                    $("#response-container").removeClass('alert-success').addClass('alert-danger');
                    $("#response-container").show();
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

The code where thumbnails are being generated:

```
 <div id="response-container" class="alert alert-dismissible" role="alert" style="display: none;"></div>
<ul class="videos<?php if ($this->related): echo ' related'; endif; if (isset($this->menu) && $this->menu == 'search'): echo ' svideos'; endif; ?>">

<input name="video_id" class="tags" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $video['video_id']; ?>" />

<?php $ids = array(); foreach ($this->matches as $index => $video_id): if (isset($this->videos[$video_id])): $video = $this->videos[$video_id]; $ids[] = $video_id; $percent = ($video['likes'] > 0 && $video['rated_by']) ? round($video['likes']*100/$video['rated_by']) : 100; ?>

<li id="video-<?php echo $video['video_id']; ?>" class="dropdown thumbnail" data-percent="<?php echo $percent; ?>" data-likes="<?php echo $video['likes']; ?>" data-rated="<?php echo $video['rated_by']; ?>">

<a href="<?php echo url($video['video_id'], $video['url'], $video['slug']); ?>" target="_blank" class="video" title="<?php echo e($video['title']); ?>">

<button id="favorite" class="btn btn-default btn-mb" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="<?php echo __('favorite-help'); ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span></button>

    </a>
     </li>
   <?php endif; endforeach; p('ctr', $ids); ?>
</ul>
```

My goal is to only click one button and not have them all fire at the same time and get the correct id into the value of my input.

Comment: You should not have multiple elements with the same ID.

Comment: `id`s are supposed to be unique within the document. Using an attribute selector selects all the elements with the provided id, and you're attaching a click listener to all of them.

Comment: already tried to set custom id to the buttons by adding <button id="<?php echo $video['video_id']; ?>" class="btn btn-default btn-mb" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="<?php echo __('favorite-help'); ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span></button> and then the button gets unique generated id.

Comment: You can also use e.target and walk from there to know which video the button belongs to. So if generating and saving unique id's is a problem, use a class and then some sibling selector to get the video element ( and hence the videos id ) that comes before the clicked button.

Comment: So you select the one that was clicked.... `$("button.favorite").click(function(e) { var btn = $(this)`

Comment: Thank you @epascarello , the button seems to be working also added custom generated id to the btn just to be sure, but now i'm facing my second issue, whenever i click the btn <input value="<?php echo $video['video_id']; ?>" /> gets the id of the video and ads it to user favorite list, if i inspect element value will output correct id from the video but if i click the button only first id will be selected from the list, also if i manually add the id to the value it will favorite the correct video, if i leave it to <?php echo $video['video_id']; ?> will only get the first id from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Change `id` to `class` as `class="favorite"` and
try this one

```
$("button[class='favorite']").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var video_id = $(this).closest('li');//video id here
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + '/ajax.php?s=video_favorite',
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {video_id: video_id},
        success: function(response) {
            if (response.status == '1') {
                $(this).html(response.count);
                $(this).prop('disabled', true);
            } else {
                $("#response-container").html(close + response.msg);
                $("#response-container").removeClass('alert-success').addClass('alert-danger');
                $("#response-container").show();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I have used `this` keyword which specifies the same element against the event is triggered

Comment: Thank you, so the button now works but the issue that remains is that the correct id is not registered in <input  value="<?php echo $video['video_id']; ?>" /> it only gets the first one from the list for example the page generates 60 videos ( thumbnails, info, etc) all with unique id's and my first id is "227" for example so if i click the button from the 5th video which has an id of "203" it will favorite the video with "227" id.

Comment: I have updated the answer and got the `video_id` from `li` tag as it's under the foreach loop

Comment: You can remove `video-` from the `id` of `li` tag or add a custom attribute

Comment: Or you can also add a custom attribute in `button` tag and populate the value of `video_id` over there as well

Comment: @epascarello `this` refers to the current event's selector. Kindly share more info about it

Comment: This is the ajax code. A simple `console.log(this)` will show that